# PHP not inserting data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Really simple code

```
$device = $_GET['device'];
$voltage = $_GET['voltage'];
$current = $_GET['current'];
$power = $current * $voltage;

mysqli_query($connect, "insert into device$device (time, voltage, current, power)
    values (curtime(), $voltage, $current, $power);");
```

The problem is, it used to work whatever device number I put. It only works with device 1. Didn't change anything with the mysql database or the php code, it just suddenly didn't work anymore, except if `$device=1`.

No errors are reported either.

Comment: Are you merging device with device name ?

Comment: What are the `$device` values that are not working? You could try wrapping the table name in backticks -> `insert into \`device$device\` ...`

Comment: how your table name becomes : device1, device2 ???

Comment: DB Scheme? Are you checking for errors with the error function?

Comment: might be a good time to read up on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Never use user data, `$_GET`, directly in your query. sanitize sanitize sanitize!

Comment: Tried the backticks, still didn't work. Yes table names are device1, device2, device3, and so on.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Table names like that are a sign you're probably violating the 
[Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Why are you splitting up data like this? Use partitions if you need to.

Comment: It's working now thank you guys! Saw the problem was not in that code, but on the number tables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
$device1 = $_GET['device']; 
 $device = "device".$device1;
  mysqli_query($connect, "insert into  '".$device." (time, voltage, current, power)
values (curtime(), '$voltage', '$current', '$power')");
```

Change Query

Comment: you show any error ?? if yes then please describe it

Comment: print the query than check what actually happen in query

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($connect, "insert into device'".$device."' (time, voltage, current, power)
values (curtime(), $voltage, $current, $power);");
```

or

```
mysqli_query($connect, "insert into device".$device." (time, voltage, current, power) values (curtime(), $voltage, $current, $power);");
```

since `$device` is an int number.

Comment: Code formatting either with four spaces or the `{}` button helps **immensely**.